# How do I print std::maps that contains integers and sets of integers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have this map that contains integers as keys that refer to sets of integers. Basically I have an std::map(int, std::set(int)).

I tried to define an iterator for the map and one for the set, but I keep getting an error when I try to point the set_iterator to a specific set in the map. I get a red line under the equality symbols that try to equate both iterators (no operator "=" matches these operands). I am using visual studio c++ 2017, and I keep getting build errors.

lines 63-70 of /mykarger.cpp

```
map<int, std::set<int>>::iterator graph_it;
set<string>::const_iterator set_it, set_end;
std::cout << "Vertix\tEdges\n;";
for(graph_it = mygraph.begin(); graph_it != mygraph.end(); ++graph_it) {
    std::cout << graph_it->first << ":\t";
    for(set_it = graph_it->second.begin();; set_it != graph_it->second.end(); ++set_it){
        cout << *set_it << "\t";
```

}

I expect the results to print like this:

```
    Vertex       Edges
    1:           2      3
    2:           1      3
    3:           1      2
```

But I get the error:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: mykarger, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>mykarger.cpp
    1>c:\users\alkamali\source\repos\mykarger\mykarger\mykarger.cpp(68): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=int
    1>        ]
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xtree(303): note: could be 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>::operator =(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &&)'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
    1>        ]
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xtree(303): note: or       'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>::operator =(const std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &)'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
    1>        ]
    1>c:\users\alkamali\source\repos\mykarger\mykarger\mykarger.cpp(68): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>, std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> *)'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
    1>        ]
    1>        and
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=int
    1>        ]
    1>c:\users\alkamali\source\repos\mykarger\mykarger\mykarger.cpp(69): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=int
    1>        ]
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xtree(303): note: could be 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>::operator =(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &&)'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
    1>        ]
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xtree(303): note: or       'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>::operator =(const std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &)'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
    1>        ]
    1>c:\users\alkamali\source\repos\mykarger\mykarger\mykarger.cpp(69): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>, std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> *)'
    1>        with
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
    1>        ]
    1>        and
    1>        [
    1>            _Ty=int
    1>        ]
    1>Done building project "mykarger.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `set<string>`?  I see no strings in your `std::map` declaration.  Since you're using `C++17`, this is a great case for usage of `auto`, so that you don't have these issues.

Comment: Extra semi-colon in the nested `for` statement.   Also, it is not possible to use a `std::set<std::string>::const_iterator`  to iterate over a `std::set<int>`

Comment: That's it! I accidentally put a set<string> instead of a set<int>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is massive and it can take while to extract the relevant information, but what it boils down to is that you're trying to assign a `std::set<int>::iterator` to a `std::set<string>::iterator`.

You have

```
map<int, std::set<int>>::iterator graph_it;
                  ^^^
```

but

```
set<string>::const_iterator set_it, set_end;
    ^^^^^^
```

A more modern formulation of the same loop avoids many potential problems:

```
for(const auto& vertex: my_graph) {
    std::cout << vertex.first << ":\t";
    for (const auto& edge: vertex.second)
    {
        std::cout << edge << " ";
    }
}
```